# Oracle 12c Does Not Check Password While Connecting Sys

Tags: oracle12c

I downloaded Oracle 12c from website and installed it. In gave Sys password as "admin", all the setup was done successfully.

now, on the command prompt, i issue the following commands..

```
SQLPlus /nolog
```

I get the SQL>

i then say "connect sys/nimda@orcl as sysdba and it gets connected successfully.

I try to connect to 12c will all sorts of invalid passwords and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, isn't it?

When you log on to the database server and that user is member of the operating system's DBA group, then - when connecting to that (local) database - you're authenticated at the operating system level and you can connect just as you tried it - with an invalid password.

You could also try, for example, `sqlplus littlefoot/mukesh as sysdba`, and it *should* work.